# Location is null unless GoogleMap is initialized again

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, kotlin

What I'm trying to achieve is to display the user's last know location. If the GPS is disabled, request the location setting. When user presses OK, then enables the GPS and moves the map camera to the location found.

It works as expected when the GPS is already enabled; however, when it isn't, the map camera just doesn't make a move because the location is null.

I can make this work if I add `initMap()` after the `else` statement (when `location == null`) inside the `displayLocation()` function, but something doesn't feel right about this solution.

Could someone please explain what's going on in here? I greatly appreciate it!

By the way, I'm using MVP architecture, so when the Activity starts, the first function that is called is `requestPermission()`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainView, OnMapReadyCallback {

private val ZOOM_LEVEL = 12
private val ZOOM_DURATION = 2000
private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 101
private val SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE = 102
private val RC_SIGN_IN = 123

private lateinit var mMainPresent: MainPresenterImpl
private lateinit var mGoogleMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mMainPresent = MainPresenterImpl(this)
    mMainPresent.onCreate()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mMainPresent.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mMainPresent.onPause()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when (requestCode) {
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.isEmpty() || grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                finish()
            } else {
                initMap()
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                initMap()
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap
    displayLocation()
}

override fun displayLoginMethods() {
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)  // disables it for debug
                    .setAvailableProviders(
                            Arrays.asList<AuthUI.IdpConfig>(AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                    AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN)
}

override fun requestPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    } else {
        requestLocationSettings()
    }
}

override fun displayLocation() {
    val mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    try {
        mGoogleMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mGoogleMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
        mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logic to handle location object
                        val latitude = location.latitude
                        val longitude = location.longitude
                        val coordinate = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                        mGoogleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(coordinate))
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinate))
                        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(ZOOM_LEVEL.toFloat()), ZOOM_DURATION, null)
                    } else {
                        Log.d("displayLocation", "location = null")
                    }
                }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message)
    }
}

/**
 * Initiates Google Map. Once it's ready it calls the onMapReady method
 */
override fun initMap() {
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

private fun createLocationRequest(): LocationRequest {
    val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
    locationRequest.interval = 10000
    locationRequest.fastestInterval = 5000
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    return locationRequest
}

private fun requestLocationSettings() {
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(createLocationRequest())

    val client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
    val task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

    task.addOnSuccessListener(this) {
        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
        // location requests here.
        // ...
        initMap()
    }

    task.addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
        if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                e.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE)
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following callbacks when status changed,

```
 private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }
    };
```